# "For all" vs. "with all"

Tags: prepositions, collocations

These examples are taken from the MacMillan Dictionary:

> **1. For all** his complaining, I think he actually enjoyed the day.
>
> **2. For all** the trouble he's caused her, you'd think she'd be happy to see him go.
>
> **3. With all** this uncertainty about jobs, it's difficult to make plans.
>
> **4. With all** its faults, democracy is still the best system we have.

Are these **"with all"** fixed collocations?

And I'm wondering whether **"with all"** has a broader scope of meaning than **"for all"** does as I think **"for all"** in the first two examples could be easily substituted with **"with all"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider "for all + noun/noun group"  at the beginning of a sentence as an idiom and a colloquial variant for the preposition **"despite"**.

In "with all + noun/noun group" "with" has its basic meaning.

Sometimes there is not much difference between the two, but sometimes they are of opposite meaning as in

1 - Mother about  her son's room: with all his books in his room it's difficult for me to clean up.

2 - Welcome back. With all your absence it was a loss on this site.

If you put in "For all" 1 and 2 make no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Actually they don't mean quite the same thing, even the ones that use the same phrase, though I can understand the confusion.

> **For all** his complaining, I think he actually enjoyed the day.

Here *for all* means *despite* or *regardless of*. Even though he complained (which would imply he *didn't* enjoy the day), I still think he did enjoy it.

> **For all** the trouble he's caused her, you'd think she'd be happy to see him go.

Here *for all* means *considering*, or *taking into account*. Given the fact that he's caused her so much trouble, it would be logical she'd be happy to see him go; but in fact she is not happy to see him go.

> **With all** this uncertainty about jobs, it's difficult to make plans.

This *with all* is similar to the previous *for all*, and actually I think I'd prefer to use *with all* in both cases. *With all* here means *considering* or *taking into account*, just like before. You could also say it means *since it's the case that...*. Given the fact that there's so much uncertainty about jobs, making plans is difficult.

> **With all** its faults, democracy is still the best system we have.

This one is similar to your first *for all* example. It means *despite* or *regardless of*. Even though democracy has many faults, it's still the best system we have.

So 1 and 4 are similar, and 2 and 3 are similar, even though they use different phrasing.

Comment: I have no idea what the role of "all" here is. Without it, would this bring any difference in the "with all" examples?

Comment: "With" has no special meaning, it takes the meaning "while a particular situation exists". And the "all" after "with" is a determiner, that is qualifying the following noun.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng The *all* is a quantifier, I guess. It does make a difference having it there; it's basically saying "considering there are *so many faults*, still..." or "considering that he complained *so much*...". You can't just remove the *all* and have the same meaning. You aren't just considering faults or complaining. You're considering the fact that those things were in *such great magnitude* ("all"), X is the result. Not sure if that makes any sense?

Comment: Well understood! I thought of sth similar. Now I'm sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the meaning of **"for all"**. They do mean **"in spite of..."**

But "with all" doesn't mean **"in spite of..."**, or **"for all"** for that matter. There is no meaning of **"with all"** other than literal meaning of **"with all"**.

As a matter of fact, all your example sentences are correct.

Comment: I couldn't find any entry for "with all" there. Do you have a link?

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/with  the 9th one.

Comment: There is no special meaning of "with all" there. In there the meaning of "with" is "while a particular situation exists". That is what I got from the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

considering the KJV Bible for the Scriptures dealing with the teaching,: 'with all' thy heart, 'with all' thou soul, ...
'For all' could never work here. 'With' can work alone as a sentence but the 'all' gives the sentence is true intensity, its completeness.
The defining makeup to its purpose forming the mindset of the speaker.